# does inputs have to match weights in a neural network (forwardpropagation)?

Tags: python, neural-network

I want to a have 4 inputs to the model below, but i cant get it to work. Even if i remote the asset command, add one more input and run, then i get an error (btw the code i have posted workes fine).

Can anyone explain to me, why i cant have more inputs than weights? I suspect that it has something to do with the vector dimensions, but i cant arrive at an answer.

```
def w_sum(a,b):
    assert(len(a) == len(b))
    output = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    return output

weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0]
def neural_network(input, weights):
    pred = w_sum(input,weights)
    return pred

input1 = [8.5, 0,65, 1.2]

input = [input1[0],input1[1],input1[2]]
pred = neural_network(input,weights)
print(pred)
```

Comment: You have a single neuron as an output right?
Then you are calculating the dot product between the weights and the input as w_sum, if what you want to do is having an input with higher dimension i.e 4 dimensions [a b c d] as is, just think that the dot product need same dimension in both vectors.

Comment: This is a mathematics question, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: weights, input1 and input all have the same dimensions. But if i change input, and add another element (and i do not want to do the same with the weights), the model doesnt work.
So how do i add another input, without having to add another weight?
@granstarferro

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do that, if you have n one dimensional inputs, you need to somehow use them in your net, and you do that by using weights, what you can do is just say like 3rd weight is same as 4th one, but that won't make sense. I suggest reading https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-beginners-an-introduction-to-neural-networks-d49f22d238f9

Answer (score 0):

Your input is longer than the weights already. Maybe you meant to write `[8.5,0.65,1.2]`. In your code their is a comma between 0 and 65. `input = input1` also makes more sense.

```python
def w_sum(a,b):
    assert(len(a) == len(b))
    output = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    return output

weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0,0.4]
def neural_network(input, weights):
    pred = w_sum(input,weights)
    return pred

input1 = [8.5, 0.65, 1.2,3.3]

input = input1
pred = neural_network(input,weights)
print(pred)
```

This code works with any inputs and weights of the same length. If you get an AssertionError, that means you inputs and weights don’t have the same length. It would be helpful if you said why you didn’t want to add more weights because that is the only way it is possible. For any pair of inputs and outputs in a neural network, the weights need to be the number of inputs * the number of outputs.